# RecyclerView is not populated with array list of objects

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm fetching some images from api and i'm loading images into ImageView using [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library, but this is what is happening. Images are loaded and probably stored as values in array of objects, but somehow that array isn't attached to adapter of recyclerview. I have tried many combination, as putting initialization of recyclerview behind the block of code where i'm adding items to array and then updating adapter using method `notifyDataSetChanged()` and that didn't give me a result. Also i have tried to put initialization of recyclerview and adapter after adding all items, but still no effects. Here is my code:

```
OnActionListener<List<Like>> onLikeListener = new OnActionListener<List<Like>>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(List<Like> likes) {
        mUsers.clear();

        for (Like like : likes) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserId(like.getUser().getId());
            mUsers.add(user);
        }

        configureRecyclerView();
    }
};
```

And inside method `configureRecyclerView()`:

```
private void configureRecyclerView() {
    userRecyler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    userRecyler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    userRecyler.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
    userRecyler.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    mAdapter    = new UserListAdapter(HomeActivity.this, mUsers);
    userRecyler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**Added adapter class to this question(Update)**

```
public class UserListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserListAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

private List<User> mUsers;
private Context mContext;

public UserListAdapter(Context context, List<User> users) {
    mContext = context;
    mUsers   = users;
}


@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_lst_item, parent, false);

    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = mUsers.get(position);

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getUserId() + "/picture?width=150&height=150")
            .fitCenter()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_ikonica_t)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(holder.userProfilePic);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers == null ? 0 : mUsers.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CircularImageView userProfilePic;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        userProfilePic = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_image);
    }
}
}
```

Now, every recyclerview list is attached to one fragment of view pager, and this is what is happening when i swipe and come back to the same fragment. Images are being loaded from cache memory. So images are loading and values are stored in array list, but there is obviously some problem with recyclerview. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I've only just joined this site, but I think I know the answer here. Please let me know if it helps.

Edit: You can also try using YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() at the end of your first method that gets the images.

Are you setting the images inside the adapters onBindViewHolder method? I recently setup a few adapters for recyclerviews and found that was the best place to do it. You seem to be passing in the array file, you just need to set it inside the recycler view.

In my constructor I pass in the a json file and save it to the adapter, to be used in the onBindViewHolder.

```
  public Adapter_Tastings(JSONObject _tastingsJSON, Context context){
    mContext = context;
    try{
        tastingsKey = _tastingsJSON.getJSONArray("key");
        tastingsJSON = _tastingsJSON.getJSONObject("tastings");
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then use the values in that file to set, as below. The ViewHolder class that's declared within the adapter holds the actual references to the Views inside my recyclerview item layout.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_Tastings.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    TextView mTastingDate = viewHolder.tastingDate;
    TextView mTastingTime = viewHolder.tastingTime;
    TextView mTastingLocation = viewHolder.tastingLocation;
    TextView mTastingPhone = viewHolder.tastingPhone;

    try {
        String key = tastingsKey.getString(position);

        mTastingDate.setText(tastingsJSON.getJSONObject(key).getString("date"));
        mTastingLocation.setText(tastingsJSON.getJSONObject(key).getString("location"));
        mTastingTime.setText(tastingsJSON.getJSONObject(key).getString("time"));
        mTastingPhone.setText(tastingsJSON.getJSONObject(key).getString("phone"));
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```